# c++ 11 include inside #ifdef

Tags: windows, debugging, c++11

In my Visual studio 2012 ,C++11 static function I have:

```
kuku* kuku::createKuku(bool enable, std::string dumpPat)
{
#ifndef ANDROID
    #include "kukuWin.h"
    return new kukuWin(enable, dumpPat);
#else
    #include "kukuAndroid.h"
    return new kukuAndroid(enable, dumpPat);
#endif
}
```

in c++98 it works , but here I have multiple errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\excpt.h(29): error : linkage specification is not allowed
1>    extern "C" {
1>    ^
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\windef.h(17): error : linkage specification is not allowed
1>    extern "C" {
1>    ^
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\specstrings.h(49): error : linkage specification is not allowed
1>    extern "C" {
1>    ^
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\driverspecs.h(133): error : linkage specification is not allowed
1>    extern "C" {
1>    ^
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\minwindef.h(42): error : linkage specification is not allowed
1>    extern "C" {
1>    ^
```

:)

Can anyone help me with it,

Thanks

Comment: Well the code you show doesn't have any `extern "C"`, so why dou you think it is the source of the error? The error may be in one of the included files, so determine which one is actually included and then look into that file. It looks like you include a header file with declarations 'n stuff. You can't do that in a function (neither in c++11 nor in any version of c++)

Comment: 1. not related to extern "c".

Comment: 2. of course you can do it in c++

Comment: well, please show the file and let us determine if it's possible. I highly doubt it, but you have the power to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 3):

An `#include` directive will put the full text of the included file exactly where the directive is. So all that stuff in "kukuWin.h" is going smack dab in the middle of your `createKuku` function, where it doesn't belong.

You'll almost always put inclusions at the top of your source files.

Comment: I suspect you're right, but technically, if the files aren't actually header files, but some mysterious code blobs, it may be absolutely correct to have an include directive in a function.

Comment: this function executed only once, as abstract factory at application init stage.

Comment: @user4108878 It's not an issue of _execution_ but of _compilation_.

Comment: @stefan Yes, the "almost always" was to discourage pedantry.

Comment: @Sneftel Hehe, sorry, I read answers with `-pedantic` by default ;-)